# How to use http.ResponseWriter and http.request as argument(Unit Testing) with Golang language

Tags: unit-testing, go

I just getting started learning Golang and PostgreSQL. For now, I tried to make Unit testing for CreateTodo function.
My CreateTodo function is

```
func CreateTodo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    CreateTodo := &models.Todo{}
    utils.ParseBody(r, CreateTodo)
    CreateTodoList := CreateTodo.CreateTodo()
    res, _ := json.Marshal(CreateTodoList)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write(res)
}
```

I tried to make Unit Test for this function... So far I wrote some codes like

```
func TestCreateTodo(t *testing.T) {
    dbData := &models.Todo{
        Title: "test-title-console-check",
        Description: "test-description-console-check",
        Condition: true,
    }

    utils.ParseBody(r, dbData) // r should be r *http.Request

    submittedTodo := dbData.CreateTodo()
    res, _ := json.Marshal(submittedTodo)
    r.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) // r should be r *http.Request
    r.Write(res)

    fmt.Println("res: ", res)
}
```

This is ParseBodu function in utils folder

```
func ParseBody(r *http.Request, x interface{}) {
    if body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body); err == nil {
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), x); err != nil {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I have a problem with passing net/http(r *http.Request). I am not sure how to pass this function like argument... I tried to receive it in TestCreateTodo(t *testing.T, r *http.Request) but not working what I expected.

Is there any way to unit test for CreateTodo function??

I really appreciate your help!

Edit 1]

I tried to make a global variable

```
var readData *http.Request
var writeData http.ResponseWriter
```

and using it in the function. The reason why I make it global variables is that I usually use it in the funcs like <w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request>, so I thought I can use as global vars too.

so I edit my code as

```
var readData *http.Request
var writeData http.ResponseWriter

func TestCreateTodo(t *testing.T) {
    // w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    dbData := &models.Todo{
        Title: "test-title-console-check",
        Description: "test-description-console-check",
        Condition: true,
    }

    utils.ParseBody(readData, dbData)

    submittedTodo := dbData.CreateTodo()
    res, _ := json.Marshal(submittedTodo)
    writeData.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    writeData.Write(res)

    fmt.Println("res: ", res)
}
```

But I got this error
[image]

Comment: Use net/http/httptest.ResponseRecorder .

Comment: Create a request with net/http/httptest.NewRequest .

Comment: First of all, thank you for your guideline! 
I'm trying to get the information about httpset. ResponssRecorder & NewReqeust as well. But.. pretty hard to get it...

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Volker, you need to create an http request. So you are missing this line:

`req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", <your endpoint>, <your body>)`

As shown by the Go http package [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http), the body must be passed as a stream of bytes. You can use bytes.Buffer for this:

```
var body bytes.Buffer
err := json.NewEncoder(&body).Encode(dbData)
```

After making your request, you need to initiate a response recorder and define the handler:

```
res := httptest.NewRecorder()
handler := http.HandlerFunc(<your handler>)
handler.ServeHTTP(res, req)
```

Then you can check if your response was as expected with the [assert](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert) package.

~ Zoe ~