# starting with Golang http.writerrepsonse

Tags: go

I am getting started with golang (already familiar with django) and im trying to display "Hello world!" string to browser

`My code`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func helloWorldPage(w http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "hello world")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", helloWorldPage)

    //Just sets up a default server :80
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

I am following a tutorial and looked up in docs, but im getting this error:

> mixed named and unnamed parameters syntax var w http.ResponseWriter

Comment: In short: The second paramater (i.e. `*http.Request`) needs a name, or use `_` if you don't care to use it.

Comment: Or name it, even if you don't want to use it (just yet): `w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request`

Comment: @mkopriva thank you for answer it worked! I didn't even assume about that haha

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use http.ResponseWriter and http.request as argument(Unit Testing) with Golang language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71262072/how-to-use-http-responsewriter-and-http-request-as-argumentunit-testing-with-g)

Comment: @TomerS no, my question is much more simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: The second paramater (i.e. *http.Request) needs a name, or use _ if you don't care to use it

So my code will look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func helloWorldPage(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "hello world")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", helloWorldPage)

    //Just sets up a default server :80
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Answer from: @mkopriva